# Count unique values in a column of a column in an array of objects

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, count

I want to count in a multidemnsional array how many from an id there are. 
id in this case would be usersnames form a playlist.

Backstory: I am getting information from the Spotify API and i wanted to count which user has added the most songs in a colaborative playlist. I got to the part where i get all of the information from the playlist.

Here is my results

```
(
[added_at] => 2018-07-30T14:24:24Z
[added_by] => stdClass Object
    (
        [external_urls] => stdClass Object
            (
                [spotify] => https://open.spotify.com/user/ina-78
            )

        [href] => https://api.spotify.com/v1/users/ina-78
        [id] => ina-78
        [type] => user
        [uri] => spotify:user:ina-78
)
```

from

```
for ($i=0; $i < $total; $i++) { 
            Dump::preattyDump($content[$i]);
}
```

and like 2000 more of these.

Logically the ids are not always the same.
So how would be the best (or any) way of doing this, since i can't get to the bottom of this..

I know with this

```
$users = $content[$i]->added_by->id;
```

I can get all of the users, only the users.

But i still need to count all the users (6) total.

Here is all my code:

```
do {
        $response = $api->getPlaylistTracks($playlistId, [
            'offset' => $offset,
        ]);

        $offset += 100;
        $tracks = array_merge($tracks, $response->items);
        $hasNext = $response->next;

    } while ($hasNext);

    $content = [];

    foreach ($tracks as $key => $track){
        $content[] = $track;
    }

    $total = count($content);

    for ($i=0; $i < $total; $i++) { 
        $content[$i]->added_by->id;
    }
```

Comment: "i wanted to count which user has added the most songs" is not the same as "But i still need to count all the users (6) total"

Comment: Are you searching for how many instances of user `id=ina-78` there are within the array?

Comment: My england is not the best, i am sorry.

Comment: @Dzhuneyt I want to know for example, how many songs has "Bob" added to the playlist, in this case "ina-78".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make an array of all the IDs, then use `array_count_values()` to get the counts for each ID.

```
$ids = [];
foreach ($content as $e) {
    $ids[] = $e->added_by->id;
}
$counts = array_count_values($ids);
print_r($counts);
```

`array_count_values` takes an array that may contain duplicate values, and returns an associative value whose keys are those values and the values are the duplicate counts. So:

```
array_count_values(['ina-78', 'ina-100', 'ina-78', 'ina-102', 'ina-102'])
```

produces:

```
['ina-78' => 2, 'ina-100' => 1, 'ina-102' => 2]
```

Comment: Wow this just...worked. Can you maybe explain how it works. Im a bit confused how simple this is... Thank you.

Comment: Which part of it don't you understand?

Comment: PS `array_column((array)$array->added_by, 'id')` in my answer, does the same thing as the foreach does here.  Basically you need an array of just that data (the id) so you can use `count` or `array_count_values` on it.  In my answer it's like this `['ina-78','ina-78']`

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix No, you have the organization of the data wrong. There isn't an array of objects in the `added_by` property.

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix Your code would be equivalent to `foreach ($content->added_by as $e)`.

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix There's an array of objects, and each of them has one `added_by` property. What he showed in the question is one element of that array.

Comment: @Barmar Well im guessing i just didnt not find the function that you are using,... since i've gotten preatty close to it, i just used probably every other function then array_count_values. Thank you again.

Comment: I understand, the full data was not clear in the answer, as it includes only one sub-element.

Comment: @roibubble I've added an explanation of what `array_count_values()` does.

Comment: It's fixed now.

Answer (score 2):

Use array column.

The basic idea is like this:

```
[['id'=>1],['id'=>2]]

count(array_column($array, 'id'));
```

What this does is array_column, sucks out everything with `id` so we do our count on this array `[1,2]`

It looks like `added_by` is a nested object.  So you can do it like this:

```
$json = '[{
    "added_at" : "2018-07-30T14:24:24Z",
    "added_by" : {
       "href" : "https://api.spotify.com/v1/users/ina-78",
        "id" : "ina-78",
        "type" : "user",
        "uri" : "spotify:user:ina-78"
}},{
    "added_at" : "2018-07-30T14:24:24Z",
    "added_by" : {
       "href" : "https://api.spotify.com/v1/users/ina-78",
        "id" : "ina-78",
        "type" : "user",
        "uri" : "spotify:user:ina-78"
}}]';

$added_by = array_column($array, 'added_by');
print_r($added_by);
$ids = array_column($added_by, 'id');
print_r($ids);
//or as a single line - we can replace $added_by with array_column($array, 'added_by')
//$ids = array_column(array_column($array, 'added_by'), 'id');
```

Output (note it was easier for me to do the data as JSON, this is just for example purposes as I can't use the API)

```
 //$added_by = array_column($array, 'added_by');
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [href] => https://api.spotify.com/v1/users/ina-78
            [id] => ina-78
            [type] => user
            [uri] => spotify:user:ina-78
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [href] => https://api.spotify.com/v1/users/ina-78
            [id] => ina-78
            [type] => user
            [uri] => spotify:user:ina-78
        )

)
//$ids = array_column($added_by, 'id');
Array
(
    [0] => ina-78
    [1] => ina-78
)
```

First we get the `added_by` from the parent array, then the ID from that set of data.  Basically we are unwrapping the array on one column.  Now that we have a nice neat array to work with, we can use any of the standard array functions on it, such as `count` or `array_count_values`.

```
 count($ids); //2
 array_count_values($ids); //['ina-78'=>2]
```

Etc.

> **array_column()** returns the values from a single column of the input, identified by the column_key. Optionally, an index_key may be provided to index the values in the returned array by the values from the index_key column of the input array.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php

Putting it all together, we can do this all on one line and skip polluting our space with a bunch of useless local variables:

**Counting total ID *(with count)***

```
echo "\n".count(array_column(array_column($array, 'added_by'), 'id'))."\n";
```

Output

```
2
```

[Sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/7b32a6e5093e50c1848464afc5598ceb974a349a)

**Counting each ID *(with array_count_values)***

For example:

```
print_r(array_count_values(array_column(array_column($array, 'added_by'), 'id')));
```

Output:

```
//count of each id
Array
(
    [ina-78] => 2
    //[ina-79] => 1 - for example
)
```

[Sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/f92942d56912f6bfe64b0197501d81ca34e9ec8d)

**One last note**

As there is no way for me to know what this is contained within, as it's not included. I just assumed it was an array.

> Here is my results

```
 /*
  What is this
  Array or
  stdClass Object ?
 */
(
[added_at] => 2018-07-30T14:24:24Z
[added_by] => stdClass Object
    (
        [external_urls] => stdClass Object
            (
                [spotify] => https://open.spotify.com/user/ina-78
            )

        [href] => https://api.spotify.com/v1/users/ina-78
        [id] => ina-78
        [type] => user
        [uri] => spotify:user:ina-78
)
```

If however it's an object, you can simply cast an object to an array with `(array)$object` or

```
  print_r(array_count_values(array_column(array_column((array)$array, 'added_by'), 'id')));
```

Hope that makes sense.

Comment: The length of the array returned by `array_column()` is the same as the length of the original array. So there's no difference between `count($array)` and `count(array_column($array, 'column'))`.

Comment: There is if it's missing an ID.

Comment: Anyway, he doesn't want the total count of IDs, he wants the count of songs grouped by ID.

Comment: `he wants the count of songs grouped by ID` is that not the same as the count of each occurrence of the id.

Comment: so is $json = my array, since im not going to copy paste the whole otuput. Or do i "paste" all my output in a json file, somewhere in my Project ?

Comment: What's the difference? Each occurrence is in a song.

Comment: in my code `$array` equals whatever this is `Here is my results`  So `$array->added_by` is just what you posted and the key in there of `added_by` - it was easier for me to do as json, so I would have the `stdClass` objects in mine just like you do in yours.  If you look at the array that was printed in output of the first example.

Comment: @roibubble `$json` is just for this demonstration, in your real code you're getting the data from the Spotify API.

Comment: I dont get a json from the api. I make my own array. Since the api limists everything to 100 max. Check my edit above. maybe it makes more sense.

Comment: @roibubble - there I updated it to match what you have. see `it was easier for me to do as json, so I would have the stdClass objects in mine just like you do in yours`  Obviously I can't use the API to test this little piece of code, so I just replicated the data structure.

Comment: `added_by` doesn't contain multiple objects, it's just a single object describing who added that song. You need to be looping over the array that contains all these objects.